# Using mocha with resharper

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, mocha.js, resharper, test-runner

Is there a testrunner for resharper that allows me to run my nodejs mocha tests?

I personally use Wallaby.js within visual studio, but at the office we only have resharper licenses. I can get NTVS to run the tests with the standard visual studio runner but it is quite confusing since most people use the resharper windows.

Comment: Still nothing? This is bad news :(

Comment: There is [a request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-404323) for it, but it won't be here in the short term I guess (priority normal).

Answer (score 0):

Not Resharper, exactly, but [Chutzpah](http://mmanela.github.io/chutzpah/) will run Mocha tests in Visual Studio's runner. You might be able to hook it together with [Resharper's custom HTML harness](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Options__Tools__Unit_Testing__QUnit.html) to get it going from Resharper.